# Run Sequentially Components in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have a component for pagination in angular .

it have `Input` :

```
  @Input('TPage') TPage: number;
```

and i pass this input in base component like this :

```
  <app-paging [TPage]="totalPage"></app-paging>
```

i need to fill `totalPage` then send it to component but first send `totalPage` to `app-paging` then fill the `totalPage`.

now i need to first fill the `totalPage` and then run the `app-paging` .

**How Can I Solve this Problem ????**

BaseComponent :

```
  id: number;
  newModesList: PageListMetadata<Newsmodel[]>;
  catid: Deletemodel;
  totalPage: number;
  totalPagesList: number[] = [];
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private newsService: NewsmanagerService) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(data => {
      this.catid = newsService.IntialDeletemodel();
      this.id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
      this.FetchData()
      this.catid.id = this.id;

    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  FetchData(pagenumber: number = 1) {
    this.newsService.GetCategoryListNews(this.id, pagenumber).subscribe(data => {
      this.newModesList = data.data,
      this.totalPage=data.data.totalPages,
      console.log('in base',this.newModesList.totalPages)
    })
  }

  SendRequestforPaging(item: number) {
    this.FetchData(item)
  }
```

and this is `app-paging` :

```
    @Input('TPage') TPage: number;
  totalPagesList: number[]=[];

  constructor() {
    console.log('in page',this.TPage)
    this.PushTotalPageInArray(this.TPage);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  PushTotalPageInArray(item: number) {
    if (this.totalPagesList.length <= 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < item; i++) {
        this.totalPagesList.push(i)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: like: `<app-paging *ngIf="totalPage" [TPage]="totalPage"></app-paging>`

Comment: The simpliest way is to put a *ngIf="totalPage" on your tag <app-paging> or you can take a look at how prefetching data (route resolver) in Angular works.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale thanks but still show me `undefined`

Comment: @mr-dortaj In which component? Child or Parent?

Comment: Your console log should be in the ngOnInit as well as your function.